# Can't use updated model with association in the same view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-4, model, model-associations

I have a @`parent` model which has many @`kids` model

```
@parent = Parent.find(par_id)
@kid = @parent.kids.first

@parent.update_attributes(params) #change parent's name
```

doing `@kid.parent` would be different than `@parent` eventhough `@kid.parent == @parent`
the only difference is a different Parent.name

this causes the view for the kid to be rendered wrong with the old parent name
in view:

```
<%= @kid.parent.name %> #=> this renders the old name and not the newly updated on
```

Is there a way to refresh the association or a model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ActiveRecord's reload](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-reload) method.

```
@kid.parent.reload # or just @kid.reload
@kid.parent.name # the new name, freshly fetched from the DB
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you search @kid after udpating @parent?  like

```
@parent = Parent.find(par_id)
@parent.update_attributes(params) #change parent's name
@kid = @parent.kids.first
```

Let s finish one job first for that perticular object and use it after one job is done.

In your case assignment is the main issue. Once you assign `@kid` object then It will be separated from the the one which is updating